# Pandas Merging Object Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've been stumped on the following problem. I have two Pandas DataFrames,

`df1`:

```
               datetime  value              specifiers
0   2021-06-01 00:00:00  11.30  [P1, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
1   2021-06-01 00:30:00   9.00  [P2, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
2   2021-06-01 01:00:00  10.40  [P3, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
3   2021-06-01 01:30:00   8.50  [P4, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
4   2021-06-01 02:00:00   9.70  [P5, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
..                  ...    ...                     ...
619 2021-06-13 21:30:00  12.35  [P44, WEEKEND, SUNDAY]
620 2021-06-13 22:00:00  17.10  [P45, WEEKEND, SUNDAY]
621 2021-06-13 22:30:00  11.50  [P46, WEEKEND, SUNDAY]
622 2021-06-13 23:00:00  16.80  [P47, WEEKEND, SUNDAY]
623 2021-06-13 23:30:00  10.75  [P48, WEEKEND, SUNDAY]
```

which is a little like a template, with the column `specifiers` being an indicator of three key properties of `datetime`. `P1`, `P2`, etc. refer to the 48 half-hourly periods throughout the day. `df1.specifiers` has `dtype = 'object'` and each of its rows are NumPy arrays.

`df2`:

```
           specifiers    value
0                [P1]     0.43
1                [P2]     0.41
2                [P3]     0.84
3                [P4]     0.81
4                [P5]     1.24
              ...                                               
95995  [WEEKEND, P46]     1.67
95996  [WEEKDAY, P47]     1.31
95997  [WEEKEND, P47]     1.90
95998  [WEEKDAY, P48]     0.01
95999  [WEEKEND, P48]     0.30
```

I would like to merge `df1` to `df2` so that the merge is successful only if all the specifiers present in each row of `df2.specifiers` are found in a row of `df1.specifiers`. For example, row 0 of `df2` should merge onto every case where `'P1'` is found in a row of `df1.specifiers`.

Comment: **1.** Provide a minimal, complete example without omissions.
**2.** Provide the output that your logic is expected to produce in that example accurately.
**3.** Provide the input as code when the list exists in a cell. **Then you can get answers easily.**

Comment: @PandaKim thanks for the suggestion, sorry that I didn't include one. I'm working on it now.

Comment: Your specifiers in df2 are not correctly ordered like df1?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to achieve that. Iterate `df2` and for each row, find out all rows from `df1` that meet the specifier restriction. Then concat all the matched rows together.

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create example dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.date_range('2021-06-01', periods=624, freq='30min')[:5],
    'value': [11.30, 9.00, 10.40, 8.50, 9.70],
    'specifiers': [['P1', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY'], ['P2', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY'],
                   ['P3', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY'], ['P4', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY'],
                   ['P5', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY']]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'specifiers': [['P1'], ['P2'], ['P3'], ['P4', 'WEEKDAY'], ['P5', 'TUESDAY']],
    'values': [0.43, 0.51, 0.62, 0.73, 0.84]
})

# Merge dataframes based on specifiers
merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in df2.itertuples(index=False):
    # Filter rows according to specifiers
    matching_rows = df1[df1['specifiers'].apply(
        lambda x: set(row.specifiers).issubset(set(x))
    )]
    if not matching_rows.empty:
        # Concat rows from both dataframes
        row_data = pd.concat([
            pd.DataFrame([row] * len(matching_rows)), 
            matching_rows.reset_index(drop=True)
        ], axis=1)
        merged_df = pd.concat([merged_df, row_data], ignore_index=True)

# Display the merged dataframe
print(merged_df)
```

In this case, the output should be like:

```
      specifiers  values            datetime  value              specifiers
0           [P1]    0.43 2021-06-01 00:00:00   11.3  [P1, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
1           [P2]    0.51 2021-06-01 00:30:00    9.0  [P2, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
2           [P3]    0.62 2021-06-01 01:00:00   10.4  [P3, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
3  [P4, WEEKDAY]    0.73 2021-06-01 01:30:00    8.5  [P4, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
4  [P5, TUESDAY]    0.84 2021-06-01 02:00:00    9.7  [P5, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]
```

However, when `df1` and `df2` have too many rows, this algorithm can be relatively inefficient. In your case (623 rows from `df1` and 95999 rows from `df2`), the running time may be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create example dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.date_range('2021-06-01', periods=624, freq='30min')[:5],
    'value': [11.30, 9.00, 10.40, 8.50, 9.70],
    'specifiers': [['P1', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY'], ['P2', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY'],
                   ['P3', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY'], ['P4', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY'],
                   ['P5', 'WEEKDAY', 'TUESDAY']]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'specifiers': [['P1'], ['P2'], ['P3'], ['P4', 'WEEKDAY'], ['P5', 'TUESDAY']],
    'values': [0.43, 0.51, 0.62, 0.73, 0.84]
})

df1[["P_id","Week","Day"]] = df1["specifiers"].apply(" ".join).str.split(" ",expand=True)
df2[["P_id", "Day"]] = df2["specifiers"].apply(" ".join).str.split(" ",expand=True)
df_intermediate = df1.merge(df2[["P_id","values"]], how="left", on="P_id",suffixes=("_df1","_df2"))
df_intermediate = df_intermediate.merge(df2[["Day","values"]],how="left", on="Day", suffixes=("_intemediate","_df2"))
df_intermediate
```

I used the data provided by the first answer since your code is not formatted correctly.

You should think of expanding those columns and do simple merges the way you like it.

Name your columns and do the expands carefully based on how many items you might find at most in each of those lists :)

```
             datetime  value              specifiers P_id     Week      Day  \
0 2021-06-01 00:00:00   11.3  [P1, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]   P1  WEEKDAY  TUESDAY   
1 2021-06-01 00:30:00    9.0  [P2, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]   P2  WEEKDAY  TUESDAY   
2 2021-06-01 01:00:00   10.4  [P3, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]   P3  WEEKDAY  TUESDAY   
3 2021-06-01 01:30:00    8.5  [P4, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]   P4  WEEKDAY  TUESDAY   
4 2021-06-01 02:00:00    9.7  [P5, WEEKDAY, TUESDAY]   P5  WEEKDAY  TUESDAY   

   values_intemediate  values_df2  
0                0.43        0.84  
1                0.51        0.84  
2                0.62        0.84  
3                0.73        0.84  
4                0.84        0.84
```